# launch asm compiled binary file with python and capture output

Tags: python, assembly, subprocess

I coded a simple asm binary file that get the arg of the user and then prints it on the screen using the C func printf.

So the code is compile using:

```
nasm -f elf64 ...
gcc -m64 -no-pie ....
```

The program works very well. I want to use it with python and doing so,  i can launch it with subprocess.Popen(cmd) (this works well too)

Buuuut when i want to capture the output of my asm compiled program  in order to parse it with python, the output is always empty ...

I tried:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
subprocess.call(...)
subprocess.run(...)
subprocess.check_output(...)
os.system(...)
os.popen(...)
```

Anyway i think i tested all the ways ... I really don't understand why the program works well on my python script except if i try to capture the output.

If someone have an idea ...., please let me know.

The asm code is:

```
; nasm -f elf64 -o test.o test.asm
; gcc -m elf64 test.o -o test

extern printf

section .text
global main
main:
    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, s_val
    xor rax, rax
    call printf WRT ..plt

    ; exit
    xor rdi, rdi,
    mov rax, 0x3c
    syscall


section .data
    s_val db 'hello world', 0
    fmt db '%s',0x0a, 0
```

The python code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen(['/home/test'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

r = p.communicate()

print(r)
```

thx

Comment: You should show your code. Make sure it's actually writing to `stdout` or `stderr`. Many people make a mistake of writing to `stdin` which happens to work for a terminal.

Comment: Use the [edit link under your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58917796/edit) to add new information into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic: you use stdio functions from the libc and then terminate your program with a raw exit system call, never giving it a chance to flush the output on exit.

Fix this by exiting your program using the `exit` function instead of a raw exit system call:

```
call exit wrt ..plt
```

Alternatively, simply return from `main` to let the C runtime startup code exit the program for you.

Comment: Perfect ! It works!